# Trying to create random number to const

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to create a random number to const value using `const_random` and get the same value

I have the following code:

```rust
use const_random::const_random;


pub mod random_id{
    const NUMBER: u64 = const_random!(u64)
     
    pub fn get_number() - > u64 {
        return NUMBER;
    }
}
```

I got always the same number, how can I fix it?

Comment: A `const` is *compiled into the binary* it cannnot possibly change in between invocations of your program.

Comment: ...or do you mean that you always get the same number when you recompile?

Comment: @cafce25 yeah, i know, i though const_random solves it, I have another options to get random value to const?

Comment: I don't really understand that question, no obviously a *constant* can not change it's value at random. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: porton1111 you need to tell us what you want, and you need to be sure the *words you are using mean what you think they mean*. In this case `const` mean *compile-time constant*, the value is generated when you compile the program and it will *always* give the same value when you run that compiled binary: if you want a new value you need to recompile. If you want to generate a random number at program start and have it be unchanged for the runtime of the program see yoric's answer. If you want a different random number at different times during the same execution just use the rand crate.

Comment: You don't want `const`, you really don't. The usage range for `const_random` is between exotic cases and non-existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```rust
use std::sync::OnceLock;

use rand; // 0.8.5

fn the_random_value() -> u64 {
    // A `static` value is shared and reused whenever you call the
    // function, and this `OnceLock::new()` will only be called once,
    // when the program starts.
    static RANDOM: OnceLock<u64> = OnceLock::new();

    // `OnceLock::get_or_init` is designed to be called only once,
    // when you reach this line for the first time.
    *RANDOM.get_or_init(rand::random)
}

fn main() {
    // This will print several times the same value,
    // but a different value upon each startup.
    println!("RANDOM: {}", the_random_value());
    println!("RANDOM: {}", the_random_value());
    println!("RANDOM: {}", the_random_value());
    println!("RANDOM: {}", the_random_value());
    println!("RANDOM: {}", the_random_value());
}
```

---

(another version, which uses the now mostly deprecated `lazy_static`)

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0
use rand; // 0.8.5


lazy_static!{
    // On the first call, this produces a random value.
    // Subsequent calls will reuse the same value.
    // Value is refreshed upon each start of the program.
    static ref RANDOM : u64 = rand::random();
}

fn main() {
    // This will print several times the same value,
    // but a different value upon each startup.
    println!("RANDOM: {}", *RANDOM);
    println!("RANDOM: {}", *RANDOM);
    println!("RANDOM: {}", *RANDOM);
    println!("RANDOM: {}", *RANDOM);
    println!("RANDOM: {}", *RANDOM);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a macro and an external dependency for something that can be easily accomplished with a [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) from the standard library.

Comment: @cafce25 I understand using a dependency for the convenience of the unstable `LazyLock`, but `once_cell` and not `lazy_static` :)

Comment: What can I say, I've used `lazy_static!` so often that it stuck :)

Comment: @yoric, thanks for your answer,  I'm trying to use the `lazy_static` solution, how can I get the number from RANDOM? Because I got an error `RANDOM doesn't implement std::fmat:::Display`

Comment: @porton1111 Apologies, there was a typo in my example. Should now be fixed.